Calculating a function and Plotting with values from a range
I need to test and demonstrate that a function works by calling it to calculate the saturation water vapor density for temperatures in the range -10 to 40, and then create a plot.
This is my function:
def psat(temp): return c0 + c2*(temp + 100)**2 + c4*(temp + 100)**4 + c6*(temp + 100)**6
With these variables defined previously in the code:
c0=-2.915127 c2=.001124901 c4=-.000000158311 c6=.0000000000123218
I think I did the coding correctly for the function to work, I just can't seem to figure out the plot. I keep getting an "AttributeError" How do I fix this?
Screenshot of code

A couple of things

in your line psat = psat( .... )  you are using the same variable name
as your function name so your function definition will be lost going forward, this isn't the problem with trying to plot but will mess you up if you try to
use psat as a function going forward
the resulting value in psat is an ndarray which does not have a .plot()  method

One way to see the results is to use the "procedural" (ie. calling functions) approach for matplotlib.pyplot()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

temp = np.arange(-10, 40, 1)

def psat(temp): 
   return c0 + c2*(temp + 100)**2 + c4*(temp + 100)**4 + c6*(temp + 100)**6

# With these variables defined previously in the code:

c0 = -2.915127 
c2 = .001124901 
c4 = -.000000158311 
c6 = .0000000000123218

results = psat(temp)
plt.plot(temp, results)
plt.xlabel("temperature")
plt.ylabel("saturation")



It would be nice to directly show your code in your question instead of linking to a picture. You need to use matplotlib to plot the function. psat can only generate values, it can not be used to make plots.
You can try something like this:
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(temp, psat(temp))

A note to the script that you linked to: It is bad practice so say psat=psat(temp) as this will overwrite your psat function. Maybe do something like psat_at_temps=psat(temp).
